# Spring Security - Custom login form not calling the AuthenticationProvider on submit

Tags: spring, security, authentication, authenticator

**RESOLVED**:

Spring Security 4 no longer seems to provide a default login-processing-url.  We must now explicitly provide it in form-login as follows.

```
login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
```

---

I have a strange combination of behaviors that has me stumped.  Found lots of tutorials and similar questions but none quite exactly like this.  I hope someone can help.

**Short version**: The login page redisplays - regardless of good or bad username/password and the AuthenticationProvider is never called (breakpoints not tripped).

**Long version**:

Step 1 - successful

- I was able to use spring security with the default AuthenticationProvider and the default auto-generated login screen.  Good.
- I was able to write a custom AuthenticationProvider and UserDetailsService.  Things worked fine, using the default auto-generated login screen.  Good.
- ... so the above rules out a lot of possible problems.

Step 2 - the problem - Setting up to use a custom login form

1) I added the form-login:

```
<sec:form-login 
login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
login-page="/login.htm"
authentication-failure-url="/login.htm?error" 
username-parameter="username"
password-parameter="password" 
/>
<sec:logout logout-success-url="/login.htm?logout"/>
<sec:csrf/>
```

2) I made sure that login URLs will be accessible:

```
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/login.htm"      access="permitAll" />
```

3) I created a trivial LoginController:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

@RequestMapping(value="/login.htm")
public ModelAndView login(HttpServletRequest request,
  @RequestParam(value="error", required=false) String error,
  @RequestParam(value="logout",required=false) String logout) {
  ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
  if(error!=null) {
    model.addObject("error", "Invalid username or password.");
  }
  if(logout!= null) {
    model.addObject("msg", "Successfully logged out.");
  }
  model.setViewName("/login");
  return model;
}
```

4) I created a trivial login.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body onload="document.loginForm.username.focus()">
  <h1>Login form</h1>
  <div>
    <h2>Username and Password</h2>
    <c:if test="${not empty error}">
      <div style="color: red">${error}</div>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${not empty msg}">
      <div style="color: green">${msg}</div>
    </c:if>

    <form name="loginForm" action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />" method='POST'>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>User:</td>
          <td><input type='text' name='username' value = '' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Password:</td>
          <td><input type='password' name='password' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan='2'>[${not empty webUser}]</td></tr>
      </table>
      <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

5) Then I setup some breakpoints in Eclipse to see how it behaves.

- The login page displays fine.
- I enter username and password and hit submit.
- Good or bad username and password all cause the same behavior, the redisplay of the login page.
- The breakpoints in the AuthenticationProvider are never tripped.

My interpretation is that the action specified by < c : url value='j_spring_security_check' /> is not triggering the AuthenticationProvider.

Note that the very same custom AuthenticationProvider worked flawlessly when I used the built-in default spring security login form.  That tells me that the problem has nothing to do with the provider itself, but rather with "reaching it" when I hit submit in login.jsp, especially since I have a breakpoint on its very first line and it is not being tripped.

I bet my error is trivial and obvious to someone familiar with Spring Security.  My thanks in advance to anyone that catches it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is resolved.

Spring Security 4 no longer seems to provide a default login-processing-url. We must now explicitly provide it in form-login as follows.

login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"

After banging my head against the wall for quite a few hours I stumbled upon the solution.  I hope this is of help to others in the same situation.